# A question about Carleman linearization

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Carleman linearization is a technique used to embed a finite dimensional system of analytic ordinary differential equations into an infinite system of linear differential equations:¹⁻²

Let $f$ be analytic and consider the one-dimensional (the multidimensional case is more intricate, but can be done in a similar fashion³) differential equation 
$$ \dot{x} = f(x), \ x(0)=x_0. \tag{*}\label{*} $$

By defining the variables 
$$ \phi_{k} = x^{k},\  k=1,2,\ldots$$

one has that \eqref{*} can be written as an infinite dimensional linear system given by 
$$ \dot{\Phi} = A {\Phi}, $$

where ${\Phi} =(\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots)$.

**Does every operator $A$ produced by Carleman linearization generates a strongly continuous semigroup?**

(1): *Torsten Carleman*, MR 1555355 [**Application de la théorie des équations intégrales linéaires aux systèmes d’équations différentielles non linéaires**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02546499), *Acta Math.* **59** (1932), no. 1, 63--87.

(2): *D. McCaffrey, S. P. Banks and A. Moser*, [**Clifford algebras, dynamical systems, and periodic orbits**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imamci/13.3.279), *IMA J. Math. Control Info.* **13** (1996), no. 3, 279--298.

(3): *Joaquín Collado and Irving Sánchez*, [**Modified Carleman Linearization and its use in oscillators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICEEE.2008.4723445), *Proc. of 5th Int. Conf. Elec. Eng. Comp. Sci. Aut. Control* (2008), 13--19.