# Generalization of Carleman coefficients to multivariable functions - Carleman tensor?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, tensor, taylor-series, fractional-iteration

Recently I learned about a matrix called
[Carleman matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix). It is a matrix used to represent function iteration with matrix multiplying.

> Carleman linearization is a technique used to embed a finite
> dimensional system of analytic ordinary differential equations into an
> infinite system of linear differential equations[[2]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236278/a-question-about-carleman-linearization)

I noticed that carleman matrix may be a generalization of [Maclaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

- I researched about Maclaurin series of multivariable function.

$$a_{kl}=\frac 1{(l-k)!k!} \left [ \frac {\partial^l f(x,y)}{\partial x^k\partial y^{l-k}} \right ]_{ x=0, y=0}$$

$$f(x,y)=\sum^\infty_{l=0}\sum^l_{k=0}a_{kl}x^ky^{l-k}$$

And I modified above to make it look like carleman matrix:

$$a_{jkl}=\frac 1{(l-k)!k!} \left [ \frac {\partial^l f(x,y)^j}{\partial x^k\partial y^{l-k}} \right ]_{ x=0, y=0}$$

$$f(x,y)^j=\sum^\infty_{l=0}\sum^l_{k=0}a_{jkl}x^ky^{l-k}$$.

Which gives me something like a **Carleman tensor. (I COINED IT)**

Is my modification correct? And if then, could you teach me how to apply this tensor?

E.g.

> How can I create a carleman tensor with multivariable functions such
> as $f(x,y)=x+y$?

(Like the Maclaurin series of a multivariate function).

**Example of desired answers**:

> The carleman coefficients for $f(x,y)=x+y$ are:
>
> $$M_{xy}[x+y]_{jk}= \cdots$$

**Also** I want to know how to iterate functions with the multivariable carleman tensors like:

$M[f(g(x),h(y))]=M[f]\bigoplus$ [Concatenate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906179/553404) $\left(M[g], M[h] \right)$

Which might *not* (mostly) be correct.

**Edit #2**

I think I need to find out how multivariable functions can be **coordinatizated** in orthogonal function space.

**Edit #3**

I suddenly came up with an idea, namely,

> Partial carlemann matrix

And

> Total carlemann matrix $:=\sum \bigoplus \text{partial carlemann matrix}$.

Hope that the above idea helps as a clue..

Comment: I found some useful material here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667017313149/pdf?md5=a8e03a24f1c3537ddfa11a782ec888c8&pid=1-s2.0-S1474667017313149-main.pdf

Comment: Please be free to comment on this. I'll be fully appreciated with your small comments as I am not an authority nor an expert(I'm just a high schooler). Are my expressions about multivirate maclaurin series correct?(I've just guessed from this answer ( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1020025/553404) and might be incorrect)

Comment: There was a critical error on this maclaurin series and I fixed it..

Comment: You have made many edits to this question during the last 7 days, which suggests that the question is not clearly formed (or that you are making minor edits needlessly)

Comment: Have you ever thought about three-way-matrices or some other generalization of the "matrix"-concept? Don't know whether this helps at all, just an idea to be checked out ....

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Do three-way-matrices and 3D tensor differ..? And I've heard a concept of GL-Theory.

Comment: What I mean by GL is General Linear group, which I've heard from @Babelfish. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885669/cutting-off-an-infinite-matrixmaking-a-finite-matrix-from-an-infinite-matrix#comment5959373_2885669

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode - I've not really experience/knowledge of this; It's more than two decades ago that I stumbled across this "3-d" or "cubic" "matrices" in some approach to generalize the concept of correlations (in statistics) and had found only a handful and only little articles about this (and also left this then myself).

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Wow, I didn't know that 3D arrays are not that popular in non-programming fields.

Comment: Just found one downloaded article "Algebras with ternary law of composition and their realization by cubic matrices" by V. Abramov & al on arxiv. (0901.2506v1) Jan 2009. But there are older articles and small books about that subject as far as I remember.